# Why Jmeter is not recording?

Tags: jmeter

I am working with Jmeter2.3.2 version and trying to record a webpage. 
I have added http proxy server under workbench and added http request default under thread group. using port 9090 and target controller test plan -> thread group. grouping -> do not group samplers.

After this setting i have started proxy server and opened internet browser selected manual proxy setting and added address as localhost with port 9090.

The issue is Jmeter is nopt recording anything.

Comment: What do you mean "Not recording"?

Comment: Remember to mark an answer. And upvote if you thought the answer was helpful :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JMeter HTTP Proxy server is not recording](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039512/jmeter-http-proxy-server-is-not-recording)

Answer (score 2):

You don't require the HTTP Request to get going. Remove it, start the jMeter proxy, record your test actions in your browser, stop the proxy server and go to run->start to run your test.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to consider alternatives to writing script through proxy:

1) using [badBoy tool](http://www.badboysoftware.biz/docs/) . 
Here is [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OX9NbYuE07I) Get started with BadBoy for jMeter script writing
benefits: easy record, easy export to jmeter, not necessary to launch jMeter while writing

2) using [chrome extension for jMeter script recording](http://blazemeter.com/blog/blazemeters-chrome-extension-record-and-edit-jmeter-script-without-using-jmeter)  without launching jMeter
benefits: You can export the script written to jmeter and/or to cloud as well and run it on the cloud.