# JMeter HTTP Proxy server is not recording

Tags: jmeter, http-proxy, jmeter-plugins

We are trying to do performance testing using JMeter.

I used the sample guide provided in jmeter using HTTP PROXY SERVER but my record controller was not recording any requests.

After doing a lot of research and here is what the complete scenario is.

I am accessing external sites using company proxy server. So, after a bit of research, I  understand I need to start my jmeter by supplying all information via command line. e.g.

```
jmeter -H 129.198.1.1 -P 8000 -u someusername -a someuserpassword -N localhost
```

Now i understand that, i don't need to confuse these settings. By default JMETER uses its own internal proxy server.

We need to configure our browser so that it uses jmeter proxy settings and i did that way.

I added a thread group, a recording controller, http proxy server with url include patterns and exclude patterns but still, it's not able to record any scripts.

What am i doing wrong? Can someone help me with it?

I used document JMeter proxy step by step which comes bundled with JMETER documentation. 
Here is my configuration

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to show what you configured. What is shown in the browser ? Are you trying to record HTTPS

Comment: Hi, i have updated to depict my configuration.

Comment: @PMDUBIK-INGENIERIE Please do you think you could help me with this question http://goo.gl/URsAFM? Please I really need some help

Comment: Related video tutorials: [JMeter Getting Started](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KI6u5pclYIw), [JMeter Browser Recording Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zYAiBwJK1v8), [How to record script for jmeter with Badboy tool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OX9NbYuE07I)

Comment: Chrome extension: [Record and Edit a JMeter Script Without Using JMeter: BlazeMeter's Chrome Extension](http://blazemeter.com/blog/blazemeters-chrome-extension-record-and-edit-jmeter-script-without-using-jmeter) using alternative solution: [BadBoy](http://www.badboysoftware.biz/docs/).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Remove everything in :

- URLs patterns to include
- URLs patterns to exclude

click on Add suggested excludes

It should work.

Currently your include patterns are wrong :

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Proxy_Server

> The include and exclude patterns are treated as regular expressions (using Jakarta ORO). They will be matched against the host name, port (actual or implied) path and query (if any) of each browser request. If the URL you are browsing is
>   "http://jmeter.apache.org/jmeter/index.html?username=xxxx" ,
>   then the regular expression will be tested against the string:
>   "jmeter.apache.org:80/jmeter/index.html?username=xxxx" .
>   Thus, if you want to include all .html files, your regular expression might look like:
>   ".*.html(\?.*)?" - or ".*.html" if you know that there is no query string or you only want html pages without query strings.

See this reference documentation for how to record:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html

If you're looking to learn jmeter correctly, this [book](https://leanpub.com/master-jmeter-from-load-test-to-devops) will help you.

Comment: Hi PMD, it is working. I did as you suggested and it started working. Can you tell me what was wrong with my configuration that it wasn't working. I am really curious to know the issue.

Comment: @PMD Thanks a lot,Ur solution proved of great help to me.

Comment: In my case it was of doing the above and completely closing and restarting jmeter.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem when configuring firefox for proxy and recording on localhost. In Firefox -> Tools -> options -> Advanced -> Network -> Settings 
there was an entry for localhost in No Proxy for.

I removed that and it works [image]

Answer (score 3):

I have faced similar problem, please see below. As JMETER proxy is running on localhost, please uncheck the below checkbox.

[image: IE_BY_PASS_PROXY_FOR_LOCAL_ADDRESS]

Answer (score 1):

Install [Jmeter Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi) which records HTTPS protocol without any issue.

Comment: Thank you so much! at the end, this is what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have done wrong writing the syntax/format for "URL Patterns to Include" and "URL Patterns to Exclude" in "HTTP Proxy Server" under Workbench. The syntax/format should be as below:

```
.*\.jsp
.*\.jsf
.*\.html
```

But, you have written forward slash(/). Such as .*/.jsp. After correcting the syntax it should be recorded.

Answer (score 0):

The Jmeter proxy server must be started before Firefox can connect to it.  JMeter has its own proxy server so the Recording Controller 'start' button has to be pushed before FF will allow access to a website.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand the issue. The issue is not what it seems, JMeter and Browser are able to interact with each other. But the thing is that How to make sure that JMeter is able to use the proxy.

Now for this, there are many way outs. I'll start with the easiest one.
Install Blazemeter Extension in your browser and start recording in it. It will provide you a .jmx file once you're done

The second one is configuring JMeter to access the proxy.
the command is changed a bit now.

```
jmeter -E https -H my.proxy.server -P 8000 -u username -a password -N localhost
```

Please note that you need to change the below values:
my.proxy.server
8000
username
password

In case you don't use a username and password to connect to the proxy, simply omit the -u username -a password part.

Reference: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server

This will work to record the script.

Now, to run the script. This may not execute the things as expected.

In that case, you have a Advanced Tab in HTTP Request Sampler, go there and provide your proxy server details there.